# how to test NSData for specific bytes values (a.k.a. header)

Tags: objective-c, ios, byte, nsdata

I have varied NSData flowing to my class. some of these could be rtf formatted strings. now I've discovered (hopefully correctly) that all rtf formatted strings begin with

```
data: <7b5c7274 66315c61 and then random other data ....>
```

now I need to be able to have a test to see if the first 8 bytes of any given NSData coming my way equal to (7b5c7274 66315c61). so I guess the question would be two fold:

1. how do I store the (7b5c7274 66315c61) value for testing purposes
2. how do I test for it against any given NSData

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTF is a text-based file format.  Those values from the `NSData` correspond to "{\rtf1\a", where the "\a" is the beginning of "\ansi".  Personally, I'd just test that the first 5 bytes match "{\rtf".  That's what the [`file`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) command's "[magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/magic.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/magic)" file uses as its test. See `/usr/share/file/magic/rtf`.

Since the match text is pure ASCII, you can use `NSString* theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[theData bytes] length:MIN([theData length], 5) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]` and then `[theString isEqualToString:@"{\\rtf"]`. If the data isn't ASCII, then the decoding will fail and the `theString` will be `nil` and the equality test will give false (because messaging `nil` returns zero), which is what you want.

Comment: thanks. I get a different error with MIN (comparison of different signs typef of (id length) aka unsigned int and type of 5 aka int). but that's OK. I'll just test to see whether the data length is at least 5 before using the test

Answer (score 3):

You can call `getBytes:length:`, pass an eight-byte buffer, and test the results that you get back.

Put an rtf file into `NSData`, get the first eight bytes, print them out, and put these eighht constants in an array of bytes in your program. Then compare that array to the eight bytes the `getBytes:length:` returns using [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/).

Comment: thank you. I might try this if other things fail. I'm not big on C/C++ so a last resort I guess. but thank you very much for contributing a possible solution.